# Transition not working with React useState hook and styled-component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

When I click the button the transition happens instantly. How can I add a smooth in-and-out transition? I want the whole  to slide nice and smooth when buttons are in focus.

```
  const [margin, setMargin] = useState("-100vw");
  
  const setStyle = (margin) => {
    setMargin(margin);
  };

  const Box = styled.span`
    display: block;
    width: 150vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 0;

    margin-left: ${margin};

    transition: all 0.8s 0.2s ease-in-out;
  `;
 

  return (
    <Box>
      <Wrapper>
        {children}
        <p>page contents</p>
        <button onMouseEnter={() => setStyle("-100vw")}>Change</button>
      </Wrapper>

      <TriangleLeft>
        <Closer>
          <button onMouseEnter={() => setStyle("0")}>Change</button>
        </Closer>
      </TriangleLeft>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I am not sure if this is an issue with css or how i am handling the hooks...

Comment: Code in the sandbox doesn't match code in the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a look in your code and you just need to do some changes:

Remove all styled components out of Field component, like this:

```
  const TriangleLeft = styled.span`
    ....
  `;

  const Box = styled.span`
    ....
  `;

  const Wrapper = styled.span`
    ....
  `;

  const Closer = styled.span`
    ....
  `;

  const Field = ({ children }) => {
  
    const [margin, setMargin] = useState("-100vw");
    const setStyle = (margin) => {
      setMargin(margin);
    };

    return .....
  }
```

Also, in your Box style, your margin-left should be:

```css
/* Completed Style: */
const Box = styled.span<BoxProps>`
 display: block;
 width: 150vw;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 0;

 /* Here you are getting the prop margin and setting it to margin-left */
 margin-left: ${props => props.margin};

 transition: all 0.8s 0.2s ease-in-out;
`;
```

And finally in your Box tag:

```js
return (
    // Here you are saying that Box has a custom prop named margin and setting it with margin state.
    <Box margin={margin}>
      <Wrapper>
        {children}
      .....
```

You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-leaf-rpk3y?file=/src/components/field.js:48-54).